# Share maps and routes to your phone using mapQuest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapquest

i'm developing a web app using mapQuest.
I have a 2 question:
1)I want to share routes from my web app to my phone,is there any possible way to do that.
2)How can i track my phone device and draw the route on my web app .
thank you for helping me.
ps: i'm using nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MapQuest mobile SDKs do not have any functionality to send or receive data to or from other applications. But you should be able to build that around the SDK. The SDK won't take a specific shape, but you can use an origin, destination, and waypoints between to create that shape.